# Debian gcc undesirable behaviour

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, c++14, static-libraries, debian-stretch

I am creating a gcc shared library having a static library dependency.

I compile the parts for static library as following:

```
gcc -c -m64 -O2 -fPIC -std=c99 -Wall  ms*.c //there are 10 C files, no warnings
```

Next I create a static library with:

```
ar rc static_lib.a ms*.o
```

Next I compile the parts for my program as following:

```
g++ -c -m64 -O2 -fPIC -std=c++14 -Wall  ab*.cpp //there are 5 C++ files, just -Wunused-variable warnings
```

Then I create a shared library as following:

```
g++ -shared -g -Wall ab*.o static_lib.a -o shared_lib.so
```

in the normal case, this shared_lib.so will be called by a Ruby program using a foreign function interface. There is no problem if I do it on ubuntu or mac(.dylib), but if I try this on debian stretch I get an error **related to the static library** as if the configurations are not set properly. If I run the application without foreign function interface, such as creating a tester and running with the cpp file main function as following:

```
> g++ -o library_test ab*.o static_lib.a
> ./library_test
```

There is no problem!

My question is what kind of configuration for creating a shared library may be missing here to not get that undesirable behaviour. Especially on debian stretch 9.5!
Or is there a way that I can understand if there is a problem in the shared library.

Comment: What *is* the error you get? And what do you really do when you get the error? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: The error I get is related to the static library as it is very specific I didn't see any point to post it here. In short, for creating the static library to remove some functionalities and to run some functionalities in a particular way, we define a configuration file including lines as following:
`#define M_NO_ASSEMBLY
#define M_MAX_BASE 64`
.....
The shared library seems to be not caring those configurations.

Comment: Seriously, the error is very specific, and **still** you don't mention it? Specific errors are good.

Comment: Library specific errors are very good also. It is "illegal modulus" error. There is a configuration M_DIVISOR defined for divisor of the modulus,  and the shared library seems to be not caring of this configuration. But, I don't have any problem when I test it on command line.

Comment: That's a strange error. I assume that it's an error message from the library itself, not from the linker. Obviously to judge that we'd need to have source code for the library, but it is entirely possible that the source code somehow depends on a macro `M_DIVISOR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, you indicate the problem is with a `#define`. Those are **preprocessor** directives. Libraries are for the **linker**.

You might be confused because `g++` does include the preprocessor phase, and might call the linker depending on the requested output. Still, `g++` follows the C++ language rules.

Comment: I solved the problem when I compiled the static library with g++. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as this was the most helpful.